# JavaScript check if array contains modified values, count unique pixels in an image

Tags: javascript, arrays, rgb, repeat, pixel

```js
var image = new SimpleImage("lena.png");
var col = [];
var uniqcol = [];

for (var px of image.values()){

    col.push([px.getRed,px.getGreen,px.getBlue]);
    
    if(uniqcol.includes([px.getRed +- 1, px.getGreen +- 1, px.getBlue +- 1]) ){
     print('not unique');
    }else{
        uniqcol.push([px.getRed,px.getGreen,px.getBlue]);
    }
}
```

I would like to count the number of unique pixels within an image. A unique pixel being one which RGB values are not within 1 to anothers pixels. I have the above code but it does not work. I think the issue that I am having is with checking that the RGB values are either +1 or -1 from the selected pixel px value. If a unique pixel is found, id like to add to the the uniqcol array. Is there any other way to count the unique pixels, or a way to check that the RGB values are within 1 from the selected px value?

Thanks.

Comment: `var +- 1` is equivalent to `var + -1`, which is `var - 1`.

Comment: If you want to test if a variable is equal to +/- some other variable, it's `var1 == var2+1 || var1 == var2 - 1`

Answer (score 2):

This tests each component to see if it's within 1 by subtracting the two, taking the absolute value, and checking if it's less than 2.

This is probably *super inefficient*.  For each pixel you're iterating a potentially massive array until you get a match, or worst case, you don't find a match.

```js
var image = new SimpleImage("lena.png");
var col = [];
var uniqcol = [];

for (var px of image.values()){
    var found = uniqcol.find(function (el) {
      return 
        Math.abs(el[0] - px.getRed) < 2 &&
        Math.abs(el[1] - px.getGreen) < 2 &&
        Math.abs(el[2] - px.getBlue) < 2;
    });

    if (!found) {
      uniqcol.push([px.getRed,px.getGreen,px.getBlue]);
    } else {
      print('not unique');
    }
}
```

Here's another approach that uses memoization.  It should be a lot faster at the expense of storing a separate lookup structure.

Edit - I deleted this approach because it can fail.  It's probably possible to do but quite tricky.

Comment: I knew there was a way to simplify my last bit of code, I forgot about `Math.abs()`!

Comment: `.some()` is a little better than `.find()`, since you don't care about the value, just whether it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for all the different pixel values, putting `+-` will not match a range of values. `.includes()` looks for exact matches.

```
for (var px of image.values()) {
    col.push([px.getRed,px.getGreen,px.getBlue]);
    var found = false;
    for (dRed of [-1, 0, +1]) {
        for (dGreen of [-1, 0, +1]) {
            for (dBlue of [-1, 0, +1]) {
                if (uniqcol.includes([px.getRed + dRed, px.getGreen + dGreen, px.getBlue + dBlue]) {
                    found = true;
                    print("not unique");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                break;
            }
        if (found) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        uniqcol.push([px.getRed,px.getGreen,px.getBlue]);
    }
}
```

This is probably not a very efficient way to do it, since it will search the entire image 9 times for each pixel. It would probably be better to loop through all the pixels, testing if all the colors are within a range of the current pixel:

```
if (px.getRed >= curPixel.getRed - 1 && px.getRed <= curPixel.getRed + 1 &&
    px.getGreen >= curPixel.getGreen - 1 && px.getGreen <= curPixel.getGreen + 1 &&
    px.getBlue >= curPixel.getBlue - 1 && px.getBlue <= curPixel.getBlue + 1)
```

A really efficient algorithm would involve sorting all the pixels (nested arrays of red, blue, and green values would be a good structure), then searching this. But that's more a topic for CodeReview.stackexchange.com.